# does reactjs have session or cookie for user profile?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-cookie

I know [React](https://reactjs.org/) is client side, but does it have session or cookie to send it to server with [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for cart and user profile?

I found [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) but, is it secure?

Comment: You can store client-side data using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

React is just a javascript library useful for creating fast web UI. Cookies and session has nothing to do with React. Use, normal JavaScript API's to handle them.
For maintaining session and local data, you can use 
sessionstorage Docs:[SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or localstorage Docs: 
[Localstorage Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redux for that but also the: https://github.com/gpbmike/react-cookie looks good based on the documentation.